# Flex Navbar doesn't display in Safari but works in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a bottom navbar and am encountering a very strange issue. It works perfectly in Chrome (Android) but in Safari (iOS) it doesn't.

The even stranger issue seems to be that "onclick" events work on the navbar, so it definitely seems to be there, it just isn't visible.

I've been at this for hours and can't figure it out. Anyone have any ideas what could be wrong?

```css
.mobile-bottom-nav {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  will-change: transform !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) !important;
  display: flex !important;
  height: 60px !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  display: block !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 60px !important;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item--active {
  color: #FF0030;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile-bottom-nav">
  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content mobile-bottom-nav__item--active">
      Section 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content">
      Section 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content">
      Section 3
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

As you can see, I tried adding `z-index` but that also didn't work.

**UPDATE**
It seems removing these 2 lines made it show up:

```
will-change:transform !important;
transform: translateZ(0) !important;
```

Comment: the click event not work ? but `onclick` is empty in your code ! provide us with screenshot

Comment: @AbdelrahmanGobarah It works; I just removed it for the sample.

Answer (score 2):

Almost all modern desktop and mobile browsers support CSS `flexbox`! You can checkout flexbox [cross-browser](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) support and [flexbugs](https://github.com/philipwalton/flexbugs) details here.

```css
.mobile-bottom-nav {
  position: fixed !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  right: 0 !important;
  z-index: 1000 !important;
  will-change: transform !important;
  transform: translateZ(0) !important;
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
  display: flex !important;
  height: 60px !important;
  background-color: #fff !important;
  max-width: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item {
  flex-grow: 1 !important;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1 !important;
  text-align: center !important;
  font-size: 0.8rem !important;
  display: block !important;
  flex-direction: column !important;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column !important;
  justify-content: center !important;
  -webkit-justify-content: center !important;
  font-weight: 600;
  height: 60px !important;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item--active {
  color: #FF0030;
}

.mobile-bottom-nav__item-content {
  display: -webkit-flex !important;
  display: flex !important;
  -webkit-flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 5px;
  z-index: 1001 !important;
}
```

```html
<nav class="mobile-bottom-nav">
  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content mobile-bottom-nav__item--active">
      Section 1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content">
      Section 2
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item" onclick="">
    <div class="mobile-bottom-nav__item-content">
      Section 3
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```